# Catching specific exception on entire android app

Tags: java, android, exception, android-volley

In my android app almost every activity does network requests, my goal is to properly react to 401 code(unauthorized) - redirect user to login screen.

Im using volley, so should I catch VolleyError exception in every activity and react to it separately - or is there possibility to catch that error on entire app so there's less code?.
What would be the proper approach?

Comment: I would say that highly depends on what the user was doing and if there could be some data that needs to be cleaned up or saved. IMHO it is bad design to react on error on such a application wide level. I would recommend dealing with errors where they can happen.